# Rubyでメタプログラミング define_methodについて

Tags: ruby

メタプログラミングRubyを読んでいて、動的なメソッド定義を勉強したのですが、
動的なメソッド定義をするメリットがいまいちよくわかりません。

仕組みについては理解できたのですが、これをやることでどのように救われるのでしょうか？

```
class Book
    def initialize(name, author)
        @name = name
        @author = author
    end

    def self.define_component(name)
        define_method(name) do |text|
            puts @name + " is so nice book!"
            @author + text
        end
    end
end

# インスタンスの作成
wilde = Book.new("the picture of dorian gray", "wilde")
shake = Book.new("hamlet", "shakespeare")

# メソッドの作成
Book.define_component :the_picture_of_dorian_gray
Book.define_component :hamlet

# 作成したインスタンスで、新しく作ったインスタンスメソッドを利用
puts wilde.the_picture_of_dorian_gray(" is nice!")
# => the picture of dorian gray is so nice book!
# => wilde is nice!
```

Comment: 読み進めていけば分かるようになっていたような。本を全部読み終わった上で分からないということでしょうか？

Comment: いえ、これが書かれてある章を読んで質問してみたのですが、たしかに全部読んでみてから改めて考えるべきかもしれません。
ありがとうございます。とにかく読み終えてみます！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

具体的にどの部分でしょうか？

```
puts Book.instance_methods(false)
```

上記のコードで現時点で定義されているメソッドを表示できます。また、

```
Book.define_component :the_picture_of_dorian_gray
Book.define_component :hamle
```

の処理で、この時点で下記のメソッドと等価する内容が存在すると認識していただいても結構です

```
def the_picture_of_dorian_gray(text)
    puts "the picture of dorian gray is so nice book!"
    puts "wilde" + text
end
def hamlet(text)
    puts "hamlet is so nice book!"
    puts "shake" + text
end
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
書いていただいたメソッドが生成されることはわかったのですが、このように動的にメソッドを定義することって、一体どういう時に使われるのでしょうか？
実用的に使われている場面をイメージしにくかったので、実際どうなのかと思いまして・・・・・・

Comment: 上記の例では、地味に二つのメソッドを定義していけば、同じ処理ができますね。つまり、この例の場合、動的メソッドを使えば、コードの重複をがんがん無くせますね。これも使い道の一つだと思います:D

Comment: 確かに、コードの重複が無くなるのはありがたいです。
まだまだ使い道はあると思うので、自分で発見していこうと思います。すみません、なんか回答しづらい質問してしまって、、、